# When do we need 3 level page table

Tags: page-tables

If we have a machine with 64 bit address and each page table entry contains only a pointer to the assigned frame. How can I calculate the largest frame size possible if we need a three-level page table? I am so confuse about 3 level page table, under what circumstance do we need a 3 level page table? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested page tables can be implemented to increase the performance of hardware *[virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization)*. By providing *hardware* support for page-table virtualization, the need to *emulate* is greatly reduced. For x86 virtualization the current choices are Intel's Extended Page Table feature and AMD's Rapid Virtualization Indexing feature.

*Three-level page table structure in x86 architecture (with PAE, without PSE).*

[image]